# Exporting complete river profile from hec-ras into ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, mapping, flood, hec-ras

Whenever i import the data from hec-ras the result is the same, what mistake am i making here?

[image: Only one tributary data is being displayed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're exporting all the reaches that you want when you're exporting from HEC-RAS.